# Ref request: If an affine subspace $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$ meets an $n$-dimensional polytope $P$, then it meets $P$ in a face of dimension $\le n-\dim V$

Tags: reference-request, convex-polytopes, combinatorial-optimization

Let $P$ and $V$ be, respectively, a bounded full-dimensional polytope and an $m$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, and assume $P \cap V$ is non-empty.

**Q1.** Could you provide me with a reference where the following (or even better a generalization of it) is explicitly stated and proved?

> > **Lemma.** There exists a face $F$ of $P$ such that $\dim(F) \le n-m$ and $F \cap V \ne \emptyset$.

This is certainly well-known *for everyone familiar with polyhedral theory* (I'm stressing it due to the tone of certain comments below), but I wouldn't say that it is trivial (whatever this may mean), and I need it as an intermediate step in the proof of a certain result in zero-sum theory. Yet, I would like not to include it in my paper, since otherwise I feel that, in the interest of my two readers, I should also introduce some lexicon and so on. That's why I'm looking for a reference.

In particular, I gave a look at A. Brøndsted's *An Introduction to Convex Polytopes* and G. M. Ziegler's *Lectures on Polytopes*, but I don't seem to find it. Thank you in advance for any help.

**Q2 (added later).** Is there any "non-trivial" generalization of the lemma to a larger class of convex sets than the one of polytopes or to something different from an affine subspace?

Comment: By connection, $V$ has to meet the boundary of $P$, which is a union of faces of dimension less than $n$. Then apply induction on $n$.

Comment: I was just about to write the same that Pietro did. This does not look like a statement whose proof should be proudly announced in a paper/book.

Comment: I don't really understand the tone of these comments. Books and papers are full of simple statements with a one-line proof which turn out to be pretty useful for some specific purposes. Are you claiming that there's something wrong with that?!

Comment: @Pietro Majer. I agree that the standing assumptions and $\dim(V)\ne 0$ imply $V\cap{\rm bd}(P)\ne\emptyset$, in view of the following: "If $C$ and $S$ are, resp., a compact and a connected unbounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ s.t. $C\cap S\ne\emptyset$, then $S$ meets ${\rm bd}(P)$" (which in turn is an easy consequence of Proposition 3, Ch. I, Sect. I.1 in Bourbaki's _General Topology: Part 1_). I also agree that the bd of a polytope is the union of its proper faces. Yet, I think this is not enough for your induction to work. That said, I'm really looking for a reference, not for a proof.